# How to get Predicted Value in a ridge regression?

Tags: regression, predictive-models, ridge-regression

How to get Predicted Value from a Ridge regression using closed solution?
I know that by applying the [image]

we get the vector of coefficients, but do we do next?

Comment: 0.8 0.6 0.3 0.3

Answer (score 3):

**Dot the feature vector with that $w$ you’ve calculated (the estimated coefficient vector), same as in OLS.**

A linear model posits that each conditional expected value (what you’re trying to predict) is a linear combination of the features.

$$
\mathbb E\left[y_i\vert x_i\right] = \sum_j x_{ij}w_j
$$

In this notation, $y_i$ is the outcome, $x_i$ is a vector of features, and $w$ is a vector of weights.

Therefore, when you estimate that $w$, such as with ordinary least squares or ridge estimation, the sensible way to estimate that conditional expected value (that is, to make a prediction) is to dot the feature vector with the coefficient vector that you’ve just estimated.

Comment: why do you do the transposed?

Comment: @ak3 Otherwise, the matrix multiplication is nonsensical. This is a pretty fundamental concept in the linear algebra underlying linear statistical models, so if you’re shaky on that, you might want to review such topics before jumping into more advanced material.

Comment: but my w is 4*1 and xi is 1*4 if i transpose the xi matrix i will get a 4*1 and then its impossible

Comment: @ak3 Then you’ve already transposed one of the vectors. Perhaps it’s easiest just to write it as a weighted sum. I will edit the notation.

Comment: @ak3 Has my answer resolved your question?